# Notation for Expresion of Tangent of Summation of Angles

Tags: summation, trigonometric-series

I am proving, assuming this expression leads to something correct, that the tangent of a summation of angles is an expression involving sums of products of the tangents of each angle, like this:
$$
\tan\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\right)=\frac{\sum_{i_1=1}^n t_{i_1} - \sum_{i_1}^n ...\sum_{i_3}^{i_2} t_{i_1}\cdot...\cdot t_{i_3} + \sum_{i_1}^n\cdots\sum_{i_5}^{i_4} t_{i_1}\cdot...\cdot t_{i_5} -\cdots}
{ 1 - \sum_{i_1=1}^n \sum_{i_2=1}^{i_1} t_{i_1}\cdot t_{i_2}+ \sum_{i_1=1}^{n} ...\sum_{i_4=1}^{i_3} t_{i_1}\cdot...\cdot t_{i_4}-\cdots
}
$$

with $t_i=\tan(a_i)$, and the nested summation of products with a odd and even number of indices being at the numerator and denominator, respectively, alternating signs as the sum progress, and stopping the progression when there is no more indices left.

How could I improve this notation, using a better way to express the nested sums with products?

Comment: I suggest using induction against $$\tan(a + b) = \frac{\tan(a) + \tan(b)}{1 - \tan(a)\tan(b)}.$$  Unsure it will work, but it would definitely be my first try.

Comment: Yes, it is an induction, but I am most unsure about the notation to use

Comment: So am I.  Unclear how appropriate this is, but when indicating that you are choosing $k$ variables from $x_1, x_2, \cdots,x_n$, with a lower index of $1$ and an upper index of $n$, the notation that I use is $$\sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k \leq n} f\left(x_{i_1}, x_{i_2}, \cdots, x_{i_k}\right).$$  Then, I will include a trailing explanatory sentence like *that is, the above represents the summation of* $~\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}~$ *terms*.

Comment: Does calling the term with $k$ variables multiplied, $S_k$ do it for you? That's how I have seen it in contexts like these.